# Фонетически самое красивое сочетание слов

Tags: фонетика

Случайно наткнулся на английское выражение "cellar door", которое считается одним из самых красивых словосочетаний многими носителями языка (см., например, [РУС wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellar_door), [ENG wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellar_door)).

Задумался, каким мог бы быть русский аналог, и понял, что в русском языке мне не только не известно единое словосочетание, которое бы признавалось самым красивым авторитетами, но даже вопрос о его существовании кажется странным.

Разумеется, существуют более благозвучные и менее благозвучные сочетания слов, но сама мысль о том, что возможно "самое-самое благозвучное" сочетание выглядит дикой.

Может ли это означать, что английский более поэтический язык, а русский - более утилитарный?

Второй вопрос: может быть, я неправ и вопрос об общепризнанном самом красивом словосочетании в русском языке может быть поставлен, и даже есть словосочетания-претенденты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это словосочетание трактовали по-разному: либо как всего лишь один из многих примеров благозвучия, либо как самый красивый случай в английском языке (It has been variously presented either as merely one beautiful instance of many, or as the most beautiful in the English language; as the author's personal choice... - из английского варианта вики-статьи).

Я думаю, что распространение именно этого примера, поясняющего удачный выбор слов при построении речи, связано с его упоминанием в известных произведениях, не более того. Не случайно один из исследователей упомянул отсутствие стечения согласных (-r не произносится), которые бывают неудачными (как напр. в конце слова sixth - три согласных произносятся без редукции). Пример из русского языка: можно сказать "погиб в бою" или "погиб на поле боя". В первом случае сочетание согласных "бвб" неудобно для произношения. Есть элементы (напр. количество слогов выбранного слова), влияющие на ритм фразы и т.п. Для литературных текстов это важно.